# How to calculate confidence interval for proportion of means

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I have a variable (v_1) calculated as the ratio of the mean for variable 2 (v_2) and variable 3 (v_3). How do I calculate a confidence interval for this ratio?

```r
v_2<-c(1,5,6,3,4,9,7,3,2,5,6,7)
v_3<-c(7,11,22,5,4,3,8)

v_2_mean<-mean(v_2)
v_3_mean<-mean(v_3)

v_1<-v_2_mean/v_3_mean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16349/how-to-compute-the-confidence-interval-of-the-ratio-of-two-normal-means) on cross validated suggests that if you are willing to make the assumption of Gaussian distribution in both samples, the `mratios` package contains the function `ttestratio()` which will perform a t-test for the ratio. More importantly for you, it will also calculate a confidence interval:

```
v_2 <- c(1,5,6,3,4,9,7,3,2,5,6,7)
v_3 <- c(7,11,22,5,4,3,8)

mratios::ttestratio(v_2, v_3)$conf.int[1:2]

# [1] 0.3000213 1.6524510
```